# Self-Service Site Provisioning (Mysites/personal sites) using Apps for SharePoint 2013 on prem

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, mysite, self-service

Self-service site provisioning in SharePoint online is comprehensively explained in [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/richard_dizeregas_blog/archive/2013/04/04/self-service-site-provisioning-using-apps-for-sharepoint-2013.aspx) but do we have similar process for on-premise installations?

I would really appreciate deep insights on how I can provision Mysites self-service provisioning using app model. My bad add-in model for SharePoint ;)